# jquery - Get the occurrence of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contains 5 images.

I want to write to a p tag every occurrence of the img

```
$("#myDiv img").each( function() {
    $("p").append($(this).length);
});
```

The above returns:

`11111`

What I want to return is:

`12345`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you can pass the index as the first argument to the function. Thus:

```
$("#myDiv img").each( function(i) {
  $("p").append(i+1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure If if I get you right, but the desired outcome should be when invoking `.index()` to get the index within the siblings:

```
$("#myDiv img").each( function() {
    $("p").append($(this).index()+1);
});
```

Since the index is zero-based, I increment those values by one here.

Probably a bette way is to just use the *index* which gets passed into the callback method of `.each()`.

```
$("#myDiv img").each(function(index) {
    $("p").append(index + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping trough each image found in your #myDiv element and then you echo the length of the current element - which will always be 1.

```
var i = 1;

$("#myDiv img").each( function() {
    $("p").append(i);
    i++;
});
```

Classic example of incrementing a counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it like this?

```
var no = 1;

$("#myDiv img").each( function() {
    $("p").append(no);
    no++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make use of a global variable like so:

```
var cnt = 0;

$("#myDiv img").each( function() {
    $("p").append(++cnt);
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var index = 0;
$("#myDiv img").each( function() {
    $("p").append(++index);
});
```

You are always accessing ONE element out of 5 when each() is called, so you always get length 1.